# Apache overrides 500 HTTP status code responses

Tags: apache, http, status

I am using Apache as a proxy server. When my web application sends a 500 error code as response to an AJAX call, apache displays it own default internal error message

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>500 Internal Server Error</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Internal Server Error</h1>
<p>The server encountered an internal error or
misconfiguration and was unable to complete
your request.</p>
<p>Please contact the server administrator,
 you@example.com and inform them of the time the error occurred,
and anything you might have done that may have
caused the error.</p>
<p>More information about this error may be available
in the server error log.</p>
</body></html>
```

Is there a way to avoid this, so that the error response doesnot get morphed by apache server.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, I was using the code: (PHP)

```
header("HTTP", true, 500);
```

instead of

```
header("HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error");
```

The first worked on my local XAMPP server but not on certain other servers, switching to the HTTP/1.0 response instead worked on both.

Answer (score -1):

Check your httpd.conf file for where Apache is storing errors.
You can then `tail error.log` to see the most recent errors or `cat error.log` to see all the errors.

If there are no errors, `vim offending.file.ext` to see if anything looks incorrect. Might be line endings or syntax errors.

Otherwise, I suggest letting us see the code.